# How do I create a function that can: replace 0's to NaN?

Tags: python, data-science

How do I create a function that can: replace  (0.0) to NaN, remove underscores, convert clean strings into a float datatype or otherwise return the converted data ?

So far I have tried the following:

```
def score_cleaner(underscored): 
    if underscored == '_000':
         return np.NaN
           
long_data['Numeric Score']= long_data['Score'].apply(lambda x:(float(x.replace('_',''))))

long_data ['Numeric Score']= long_data ['Score'].apply(score_cleaner)
```

However this has resulted in either an output of endless "NaNs", or all the numerical values rather than a combination of the two where 0.0's are converted to NaNs and the rest of the data is left alone:

```
PID_Sex PID_Age ManipulationScoreFace IDCondition Numeric Score
103 Female  18  Symmetry    _005    101 Manipulated NaN
106 Female  19  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN
106 Male    22  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN
109 Male    20  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN
112 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN 
115 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN
118 Female  19  Symmetry    _003    101 Manipulated NaN
121 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated NaN
124 Female  19  Symmetry    _004    101 Manipulated NaN
127 Female  19  Symmetry    _005    101 Manipulated NaN

PID_Sex PID_Age ManipulationScoreFace IDConditionNumericScore
103 Female  18  Symmetry    _005    101 Manipulated 5.0
106 Female  19  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
106 Male    22  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
109 Male    20  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
112 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
115 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
118 Female  19  Symmetry    _003    101 Manipulated 3.0
121 Female  18  Symmetry    _000    101 Manipulated 0.0
124 Female  19  Symmetry    _004    101 Manipulated 4.0
127 Female  19  Symmetry    _005    101 Manipulated 5.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "left alone"? What is your output supposed to look like? `'_000'` to a float `np.nan` AND `'_003'` etc. to `3.0` **OR** `'_000'` to `'NaN` and `'_003'` to `'_003'` (leave it as it is)?

Comment: so the original messy data is '_000', my output is supposed to look like '0.5' etc. depending on the participant's score (left alone). However for the 0.0 scores.. I am to replace those with NaNs. and this is specific to the 'Numeric Score' Column.

Comment: So what's the **desired output for `'_005'`**?

Comment: Let me correct myself if the original is "_003" output is 3.0, if it's '_005' then output would be 5.0.. the Score column is being converted into the "Numeric Score" column.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the clarification! So **Option 1** of my answer should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much @Scotty1- I appreciate your patience !

Comment: You are welcome and may also accept/upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly get what you want, so here are the two most likely options:

---

#### Option 1

Convert the column to `float` type with `'_000'` being converted to `np.nan` and the rest to numeric values:

```
long_data['Numeric Score'] = long_data['Score'].str.replace('_', '').astype(float).replace(0., np.nan)
```

or as a function definition:

```
def score_cleaner(underscore):
    return underscore.str.replace(
        '_', '').astype(float).replace(0., np.nan)

long_data['Numeric Score'] = score_cleaner(long_data['Score'])
```

---

#### Option 2

Convert the column to `object` type with `'_000'` being converted to the string `'NaN'` and leave the rest as it is:

```
long_data['Numeric Score'] = long_data['Score'].str.replace('_000', 'NaN')
```

and again defined as a function:

```
def score_cleaner(underscore):
    return underscore.str.replace('_000', 'NaN')

long_data['Numeric Score'] = score_cleaner(long_data['Score'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a function? Sorry I am trying to follow specific instructions: "create a function below, which takes an argument called underscored. Your function needs to do several things: Use string methods to remove or replace the underscore. Convert the cleaned string into a float data type. Check whether the converted data is 0. If so, return a NaN. Otherwise, the function should return the converted data." –

Comment: Yes, I had already added the function which does exactly what you want. I just had to rename the argument `data` to `underscore`. You need that function for some edX or coursera homework?

Comment: I'm not sure what edX is sorry, but It's for an course homework. I'm only starting to learn how to use python it's my first course.

Comment: edX is an online course platform where many universites offer f.i. python and data science courses. Good luck! It is worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['Numeric Score'] = df['Score'].apply(lambda x:(float(x.replace('_',''))))
df['Numeric Score'][df['Score'] == '_000'] = np.NaN
```

To create a function you could you this:

```
def score_cleaner(underscored): 
    if underscored == '_000':
         return np.NaN        
    else:
        return float(underscored.replace('_',''))

long_data ['Numeric Score']= long_data['Score'].map(score_cleaner)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a function? Sorry I am trying to follow specific instructions:                        "create a function below, which takes an argument called underscored. Your function needs to do several things:

Use string methods to remove or replace the underscore.
Convert the cleaned string into a float data type.
Check whether the converted data is 0. If so, return a NaN. Otherwise, the function should return the converted data."

Comment: I'd avoid using `apply` on columns when there is a vectorized/implemented method.